# Vector Drawables Icons for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, icons, android-vectordrawable

I converted an .svg file using the Configure Android Studio to measurements below as android recommends but the icons were so small. Does anyone have any ideas on why this happened?

```
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
```

Comment: Give custom height and width in icon.xml

Comment: Can you post the SVG that you were converting?